# CSS float div vertical fill

Tags: html, css

I want to float 2 columns but one of the columns is shorter than the other. How do I make them equal length?

Here's an example HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="right">
        Text row 1<br>
        Text row 2<br>
        Text row 3
    </div>
    <div class="left">
        Foo Bar
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.left {
    width:80px;
    background-color:#eee;
}

.left, .right {
    padding:5px;
    float: right;
}
```

This is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwzg4vyd/).

Comment: Set it's width by using %

Comment: This article might help you: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-equal-height/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.left {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    background-color:#eee;
}

.right {
    float: right;
    width:50%;
    background-color:lime;
}
```

[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/7em3oqge/)

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem of them having different lengths though.

Answer (score 1):

Following is one of the methods to achieve this:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="cell">...</div>
    <div class="cell">...</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    display:table;
}
.cell {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

[**See updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/jwzg4vyd/1/)

Comment: Using table's nature that will always divide in same width column no matter how much it will take. You're so genius. Vote 1 for you

Comment: Good. That is not LENGTH!! That is HEIGHT. Edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible in HTML/CSS. You can count higher col height using JS and set to shorter one, or better, you backgrond image and set to parent node.

```
.wrapper {
    background: url('...'); 
    overflow: hidden; /* due to floating elements */ 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only applying the width to .left

change to:

```
.wrapper {
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.left {
    background-color:#eee;
}

.left, .right {
    width:80px;
    padding:5px;
    float: right;
}
```